# INsert value with Asp to excelsheet and call function?

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I've got a real problem.. 
I got an webpage writen in traditionel Asp. What i need to do now is to insert a value to a field in a excelsheet. The thing is that the excelfile also contains som sub routines and i also what to call one of thoose routines after i inserted the value in the field.. Is this even posible?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It's all possible (although you may have problems with security in automating Office from ASP, since the IUSR user generally does not have permission to do much), but it's not a great idea, since Office is not designed to be used in a multi-threaded / multi-user environment. If this is for an intranet, then it may be OK. If it's for a public website, I'd suggest finding some other route.

Those issues aside, driving Excel from ASP is no different from driving it from VBA, VBScript or VB. You can open workbooks, make changes, even call methods defined as VBA within the workbook. For the latter, use the Application.Run method.

---

EDIT: some sample code (from memory - may be full of syntax errors!)

```
Set oExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set oWorkbook = oExcelApp.Open("file.xls")

Set oWorksheet = oWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

oWorksheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "foo"

oExcelApp.Run "'file.xls'!macroname"

oWorkbook.Save

oWorkbook.Close

oExcelApp.Quit
```

Comment: Alright iäve searcched alot and found som code but there is a problem. You are right, this is for a Intranet and i think this is the best solution, if i can get it to work :) I tried the following code: `code` Set oExcel = CreateObject ("Excel.Application") oExcel.Workbooks.Open(server.MapPath("test.xls")) oExcel.worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).value= "1" ' `code` On the line where i try to write to the cell the page just locks, if i removed it works. BUt if tnot the webpage just loads without showing anything.. I gave the IUSR full rights to the file also...

Comment: @Evilaid: your problem here is that the Application object has no worksheets method. See my updated answer for sample code (you need to specify a workbook first).